# rich:tab apply CSS ontableave

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

Can anyone tell me how to change the tab header color on leaving the current tab.

It seems there is an property already available "ontableave", but i am not sure how to call the css on ontableave property.

I am using Richfaces 3.3 & JSF 1.2

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try FireBug and jQuery on some css class, I do not have Richfaces 3.3 installed, but there should be some difference in the classes between selected and non-selected tabs.

Comment: actually in our application we got ten tabs, the user has to process one by one, so to differentiate the processed tabs with unprocessed i just want to change the processed tabs header color.

can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any DOM element, you have the `setAttribute` method. So all you have to do is obtain a reference to the RF tab with   `#{rich:component('yourTabId')}`. So putting it all together, you can have

```
    ontableave= "#{rich:component('yourTabId').setAttribute('style','color:red')}"
```

or you could do it all in raw JavaScript(in case the RF people have disabled the method on their component as the PF components have) where you'll have a function

```
<script>

    function changeColor() {
        this.style.color = '#cc0000';
     }

</script>
```

and then call the function in `ontableave`